# Regarding Route.config file and attribute routing ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

We know route is register in route.config file like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductPage",
    url: "{productId}/{productTitle}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Show" },
    constraints: new { productId = "\\d+" }
);
```

Can we delete routing related code from route config file and implement attribute routing instead?

See this

```
[Route("{productId:int}/{productTitle}")]
public ActionResult Show(int productId) { ... }
```

Can we use the above attribute routing instead? 
Can we delete all routing related code from route config file, so my route config would look like?

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

Please help me to have control over this routing issue. Thanks

Comment: Mvc5 you can if you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, but it's better to keep one default route in `RouteConfig` and add decorate other action methods with route attributes.